# Filter arrays of different shapes in dictionary by index

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

If I have a dictionary where all its elements are of the same shape, I can filter those elements by index as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import random

# Some random data
a1 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 1000)
a2 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 1000)
a3 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 1000)
# Some random indexes
idx = random.sample(range(0, 1000), 25)
# My dict
aa = {'a1': a1, 'a2': a2, 'a3': a3}
# New filtered dict
bb = {k: v[idx] for k, v in aa.iteritems()}
```

But if the elements within the dictionary have different shapes:

```
a1 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., 1000)
a2 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (3, 1000))
a3 = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (5, 1000))
```

the above does not work anymore. Is there a way to generalize the filtering to work on arrays of different shapes (but equal lengths)?

Comment: What do you mean by _"...arrays of different shapes (but equal lengths)"_? Does the `length` refer to `size` (defined as product of all numbers in the `shape` tuple) or as the last dimension in the `shape` tuple?

Comment: It refers to the last dimension. In this case, all arrays have lengths of `1000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ellipsis:

```
bb = {k: v[..., idx] for k, v in aa.items()} # In Python 2.7 use iteritems()
```

From https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html:

> `Ellipsis` expand to the number of `:` objects needed to make a selection tuple of the same length as `x.ndim`.

Comment: Excellent, I always forget about this feature. Thank you!